# laravel create select element with different data

Tags: php, laravel

I want to call a function, and this function will create `select option` element on my view. ex:

```
{{ select_option($users, $key = 'id', $value = 'name') }}
```

And this is my `select_option` will include `html`

**1 solution**

**MyHelper.php**

```
function select_option($datas, $key, $value) {
    $html = '<select>';
    foreach ($datas as $data) {
        $html .= "<option key='{$data->$key}'>{$data->$value}</option>"
    }
    $html .= '</select>';

    return $html;
}
```

**Edit use blade template**

I know I should use blade template, but I need to pass data by myself. I want just call a function.

```
function select_option($datas, $key, $value) {
    return view(
            'select_option',
            ['datas' => $datas ?? []]
        )->render();
}
```

But I think it's weird because I use PHP to create HTML element.

**2 solution presenter**

**2-1 pass data to presenter**

I must get data from Controller. But I want to call a function and get data at once.

```
@inject('SelectOption', 'App\Presenter\SelectOption')
{!!$SelectOption->getData($datas)!!}
```

---

**getData**

```
public functin getData($datas) {
    // foreach to create select option element
    return $html
}
```

**2-2 presenter will call service to get data**

I think Presenter call services is weird too. I'm not sure the render time will increase.

```
@inject('SelectOption', 'App\Presenter\SelectOption')
{!!$SelectOption->getData()!!}
```

**getData**

```
public function __construct(MyServices $my_services)
{
    $this->my_services = $my_services;
}  

public functin getData() {
    $datas = $this->my_services->getData();

    // foreach to create select option element

    return $html
}
```

Do you have any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: are you using blade? you can use @foreach in blade view

Comment: I know I can use `@foreach`, but if I have a lot `select option`, I need to write a lot `@foreach`. I want to omit it. And create a function to get data with auto generate `select option`.

Comment: better you create separate blade template for select and include is

Comment: @iCoders, ok I will use blade template, but I think the data should put it in my controller or presenter? or?

Comment: ya in controller you have to put or else you can use view share

Comment: @iCoders, I think I got the better answer, view share. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use View share

**Sharing Data With All Views**

Occasionally, you may need to share a piece of data with all views that are rendered by your application. You may do so using the view facade's share method. Typically, you should place calls to share within a service provider's boot method. You are free to add them to the AppServiceProvider or generate a separate service provider to house them:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        View::share('key', 'value');
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**View Composers**

View composers are callbacks or class methods that are called when a view is rendered. If you have data that you want to be bound to a view each time that view is rendered, a view composer can help you organize that logic into a single location.

For this example, let's register the view composers within a service provider. We'll use the View facade to access the underlying Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory contract implementation. Remember, Laravel does not include a default directory for view composers. You are free to organize them however you wish. For example, you could create an app/Http/ViewComposers directory:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register bindings in the container.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        // Using class based composers...
        View::composer(
            'profile', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\ProfileComposer'
        );

        // Using Closure based composers...
        View::composer('dashboard', function ($view) {
            //
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Ref:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#sharing-data-with-all-views